# What is the westerly index?

Tags: meteorology

The westerly index, appears in a CPL syllabus but I can't find much info on it, I assume it is a measure of how systems move from west to east in the southern hemisphere.

How exactly is it calculated, and what is it's purpose and significance for aviation?

Comment: [Related question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/mpy2uk/what_is_the_westerly_index/)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd hazard a guess and say it's related to the [Westerlies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westerlies), prevailing winds from west to east between 30 and 60 degrees lat.

Comment: Weather systems move from West to East in the Northern hemisphere too.

Comment: "*The Westerly Index (WI) is defined as the proportion of days per month with prevailing wind coming from the west in a four point quadrant (wind blowing between 225 and 315 degrees)*". Used to study the variability of [Westerlies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westerlies). It is related to a defined area, e.g. south hemisphere, Asia, etc. [Here for the English Channel](https://presentations.copernicus.org/EMS2011/EMS2011-435_presentation.pdf). WI data set [example](https://www.upo.es/vareclim/Data/WI.txt) for the same area.

Answer (score 7):

The only mention of it I could find in relation to a CPL is from a [New Zealander CPL syllabus](https://www.aviation.govt.nz/assets/publications/pilot-syllabus-assistance-archive/Subject-No-20-CPL-Meteorology.pdf) (govt.nz; PDF).

Including NZ in the search leads to this definition:

> The **westerly index** is the Trenberth Z1 index ([Trenberth 1976](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Fluctuations%20and%20trends%20in%20indices%20of%20the%20Southern%20Hemisphere%20circulation.&author=K.%20E.%20Trenberth&publication_year=1976&volume=102&pages=65-75)), which is the departure of the monthly mean pressure difference between Auckland and Christchurch (near 44°S) from its mean over the 1961–90 period.
>
> — [journals.ametsoc.org](https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/apme/46/5/jam2491.1.xml)

From that definition, a pilot needs to be aware of the pressure difference between Auckland and Christchurch.

---

Others here may be able to expand on its usage (feel free to reuse, anyone).

From an Earth Science perspective, I asked on the sister site: [What does a change in the mean pressure across 750 km indicate/signify?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/21094)